# Android custom button unwanted flickering black border when pressed

Tags: android, xml

I've come across a weird problem that I can't find anything about online. I have created a custom selector that has a default layout-list and switches to another one when pressed. It looks like this (button.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- pressed -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/fbutton_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <!-- default -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/fbutton_unfocused"/>
    </selector>
```

These is what the layout-lists look like http://pastebin.com/ezZB8a8U.

and this is an example button

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="40dp"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

Now the problem is that pressing the button creates a random black border filling its width and height (holding down the button causes the border to flicker). This doesnt occur on my Samsung Galaxy Tab A but it does on my Sony Xperia Z3+. This occurs at random but when it happens it seems to keep happening until I restart the activity so either it happens every press or not at all, depending on if the activity is "bugged(?)".

I hope you understand my problem, English is not my native language. And by the way I do not do anything to the button programmatically.

Thanks!

Update: One of my friend tried the application on his phone which is an older htc, he gets the same flickering border. Also tried it on samsung galaxy s5 and on that device it does not happen. Haven't been able to solve it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <layer-list>
        <item
           android:bottom="2dp"
           android:left="2dp"
           android:right="2dp"
           android:top="2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke
                   android:width="1dp"
                   android:color="#BFBFBF" />

                <gradient
                   android:angle="90"
                   android:centerColor="#e5f0ff"
                   android:endColor="#b3d3ff"
                   android:startColor="#99c4ff" />

                <padding
                   android:bottom="5dp"
                   android:left="5dp"
                   android:right="5dp"
                   android:top="5dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

<!-- unpressed -->
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item
           android:bottom="2dp"
           android:left="2dp"
           android:right="2dp"
           android:top="2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke
                   android:width="1dp"
                   android:color="#BFBFBF" />

                <gradient
                   android:angle="90"
                   android:centerColor="#F4F4F4"
                   android:endColor="#E5E5E5"
                   android:startColor="#d3d3d3" />

                <padding
                   android:bottom="5dp"
                   android:left="5dp"
                   android:right="5dp"
                   android:top="5dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Small syntax error `<item android:state_pressed="true"/>` should be `<item android:state_pressed="true">` for others who want to try. 

This did not fix my problem though, the random border still appears somehow, but thanks a lot for trying and help. :)